# C format specifier

Tags: c, format-specifiers

While i am working ,somewhere inside the code i saw the following staements.
I am getting confused by the format specifier in `sprintf`

```
   d_number = strtol( tmp_buf , (char **)NULL, 16);
   memset( tmp_buf , ' ' , sizeof( tmp_buf ) );
   sprintf( tmp_buf , "%0.*d" , (int)sizeof( dec_number ) , d_number  );
```

could anybody explain please?

Comment: @qrdl: and  that is helpful how, exactly? You may have missed the memo, but SO was never intended as a simple link to Google. It was intended to contain answers to programming questions big and small. If you have nothing useful to contribute, don't bother commenting.

Comment: @jalf The first hit is to Wikipedia article about printf, and it lists all format specifiers and width params. I hope this answers your questions about helpfulness of my comment. I strongly believe that ability to find information is one of the strongest qualities of good programmer (like any engineer), so I prefer to give a fishing rod, rather then fish. I'm proud of being programmer and don't like people who cheapen my craft. Yeah, and please make sure I get another copy of that memo, Mr Lumbergh.

Comment: @qdrl: It does. Your comment was not helpful. One of the stated goals of SO is to provide answers *without* telling people to google it. But tell me, why is it "cheapening your craft" if people go to stackoverflow.com and type in "printf format specifiers", but it's worthwhile and completely different if they go to google or wikipedia and do the *exact* same thing? I'd say the hallmark of a good programmer is going to a *relevant* site to look for information. For programming questions, SO is a more relevant site than wikipedia, isn't it?

Comment: If the question has already been asked on SO, then by all means post a link to that, and tell the OP to get off his butt and search the site before asking. But if it hasn't been asked here, **why shouldn't it**? Quoting the FAQ, "No question is too trivial or too "newbie"". So why shouldn't people looking for info on printf format specifiers be able to find answers on this site?

Comment: @jalf As soon as people like OP discover SO, they stop investing their time into learning things, because it is much easier to use SO's collective wisdom. I, for one, never answer questions like this, because it smells like karma whoring. And please tell me - why don't we solve homeworks here? What's the difference between people who are too lazy to solve homework and people who are too lazy to learn things themselves? You **really** think these people don't cheapen our craft?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.*` means the precision is not specified in the format  string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted. (d_number)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 0):

The * is replaced by (int)sizeof(dec_number). If dec_number is an int, on many machines it is the same as %0.4d. This is the *precision* with which to print the integer or the maximum number of digits to print.

The * can appear on either side of the ".", for example:

```
sprintf(tmp_buf, "%*.*", 0, (int)sizeof(dec_number), d_number);
```

also works.